# How can I import a container to ACR and configure it to be a linux platform container?

Tags: linux, azure, docker, azure-container-registry

When building my docker image locally and import it to Azure Container Registry (ACR), the Image platform is Windows. It should be Linux. How can I import my image as a Linux platform?

I am using this command to import the image to my ACR.

```
az acr import
```

Comment: The title asks about import but the question asks about upload.. which one do you mean?

Comment: import, sorry for the confusion

Comment: I think you want to push the image that you've built to the ACR, no ?   How does the dockerfile of your image looks like ?    You should have a base image that targets linux.

Comment: @FrederikGheysels, I did a dotnet core web app and I have a docker file. I then build the image and import that image to ACR.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following command to import from another ACR from a different subscription.

```
az acr import --name <DESTINATION-ACR> --force\
--source <SOURCE-ACR-NAME>/IMAGE-NAME:IMAGE-TAG \
--image IMAGE-NAME:IMAGE-TAG \
--username <USERNAME> \
--password <PASSWORD>
```

Answer (score 1):

By using the command `az acr import` means that you can import an image to an Azure Container Registry **from another Container Registry**. So you should have container images from a public registry or another Azure container registry, in the same or a different Azure subscription or tenant or from a non-Azure private container registry. Read [Import container images to a container registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-import-images) for more details.

In this case, if you have built the images locally, you can push the images directly to the ACR instead of using import. You can make it as the [Tutorial: Create an Azure container registry and push a container image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-tutorial-prepare-acr):

log in to your Azure Container Registry instance

```
az acr login --name <acrName>
```

tag the image with the full name of the registry's login server.

```
docker tag <localImage> <acrLoginServer>/<acrRepository>:<tag>
```

Push image to Azure Container Registry

```
docker push <acrLoginServer>/<acrRepository>:<tag>
```

Comment: Thanks Nancy, I am following all this steps but when I import the container to ACR. The container is labeled in ACR as a windows platform and I need it to be Linux.

Comment: Do you follow that steps to push dockerfile image locally to Acr？ Does the dockerfile image made as a linux platform when you build it locally？

Comment: How do you import the container to ACR? If you follow [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-tutorial-prepare-acr) in this push a container image to ACR, it should be a Linux platform for the ACR.